# Adding attributes to a join model during assignment to parent model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following setup:

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130923235150) do

  create_table "addresses", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "user_addresses", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "address_id"
    t.string   "purpose"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_address
  has_one :primary_shipping_address, through: :user_address, class_name: :UserAddress, source: :address
  has_one :primary_billing_address,  through: :user_address, class_name: :UserAddress, source: :address
end
```

Address.rb:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_address
  has_one :primary_shipping_user, through: :user_address, class_name: :UserAddress, source: :user
  has_one :primary_billing_user,  through: :user_address, class_name: :UserAddress, source: :user
end
```

UserAddress.rb:

```
class UserAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :address
end
```

When someone does `user.primary_billing_address = address`, I want the join model instance to have "billing" set as its purpose. Similarly with shipping and "shipping". Ex.

```
irb(main):013:0> u = User.new
=> #<User id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):014:0> a = Address.create
=> #<Address id: 3, created_at: "2013-09-24 00:13:07", updated_at: "2013-09-24 00:13:07">
irb(main):015:0> u.primary_billing_address = a
=> #<Address id: 3, created_at: "2013-09-24 00:13:07", updated_at: "2013-09-24 00:13:07">
irb(main):016:0> u.save!
=> true
irb(main):017:0> u.user_address
=> #<UserAddress id: 2, user_id: 3, address_id: 3, purpose: nil, created_at: "2013-09-24 00:13:18", updated_at: "2013-09-24 00:13:18">
(not what I want... purpose should be "billing")
```

How can I do this such that it works for new **AND** persisted records?. I've come up with solutions that are 90% there, but break on some random spec due to an edge case my approach didn't catch.

The trickiest part to work around is how `association=` behaves: on new records, it queues the association for assignment through the join model.

PS: I left out the conditionals on the `has_one` relationships that I'd use to get the address I want. I think this issue is independent of that.

Comment: I think you would want a before_save method defined to check for the setting of the billing address and set the purpose appropriately?

Comment: How would I know which purpose to assign?

Answer (score 1):

First, the associations are a bit off, both `primary_shipping_address` and `primary_billing_address` will return same address. You can change it to

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_addresses # user can have multiple addresses one for shipping and one for billing
  has_one :primary_shipping_address,
           through: :user_address, class_name: :UserAddress, 
           source: :address, :conditions => ['user_addresses.purpose = ?','shipping']

  has_one :primary_billing_address, 
          through: :user_address, class_name: :UserAddress, 
          source: :address, :conditions => ['user_addresses.purpose = ?','billing']
end
```

To save the purpose while saving the address, there are two options.

**Option 1 : Override the default `association=` method**

```
   # alias is needed to refer to original method
   alias_method :orig_primary_billing_address=, :primary_billing_address=
   def primary_billing_address=(obj)
     self.orig_primary_billing_address = obj
     self.user_addresses.where("address_id = ?", obj.id).update_attribute(:purpose, 'billing')  
   end

  # repeat for shipping
```

**Option 2 : Create a custom method (I prefer this as it is cleaner and DRY)**

```
   def save_address_with_purpose(obj,purpose)
      self.send("primary_#{purpose}_address=", obj)
      self.user_addresses.where("address_id = ?", obj.id).update_attribute(:purpose, purpose)  
   end
```